# how to find a maximal common isotropic subspace of 2 bilinear forms?

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

Given bilinear forms $B_1 , B_2 : V \times V \to k$, where $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space over the field $k$, we say that $W \subset V$ is an **isotropic** subspace of $V$ with respect to $B_1$ if $B_1|_W  =0$ (restriction of $B_1$ to $W$ is zero).

How does one find a maximal common isotropic subspace of $B_1$ and $B_2$? I tried computing maximal isotropic subspaces of $B_1$ and $B_2$ and taking their intersection, it is a common isotropic subspace, but not maximal. (And often it is just $\{0\}$ )

Feel free to give partial results (e.g. specialize $k$). Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could find a maximal isotropic subspace $W$ of $B_1$ and then study the restriction of $B_2$ to $W$ and find a maximal isotropic subspace of **that**. All maximal common isotropic subspaces arise that way. However, I'm not sure that taking an arbitrary $W$ will give you a maximal one...

Comment: That makes sense to me, thanks!

Comment: Indeed, taking arbitrary $W$ will not give a maximal common isotropic subspace. It seems a good idea to pick $W$ in such a way that the rank of $B_2|_W$ is minimized. Is this possible?

Comment: I thought about it. I don't know, I'm sorry. Let me know if you find something, I'm interested.